# How to change locally titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

Please, consider this code

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ hoyningen:1993,
  author         = "Hoyningen-Huene, Paul",
  title          = "Recontructing Scientific Revolutions",
  publisher      = "The University of Chicago Press",
  location       = "Chicago",
  year           = "1993",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0pt}
\titlecontents{chapter}[4pc]{\addvspace{1pc}}
{\contentsmargin {0 pt}\makebox[0pt][r]{\quad\makebox[30pt][r]{\textsc{\romannumeral
\thecontentslabel\quad}}}}
{}
{}
{}

\contentsmargin{0pt}
\titlecontents{section}[4pc]
{\contentsmargin {0 pt}\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentspage\quad\makebox[30pt][r]{\textsc{\thecontentslabel.\quad}}}}
{}
{}
{}

\contentsmargin{0pt}
\titlecontents{subsection}[4pc]
{\contentsmargin {0 pt}\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentspage\quad\makebox[30pt][r]{\textsc{\thecontentslabel.\quad}}}}
{}
{}
{}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section one}
\section{Section two}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section one}
\section{Section two}
\section{Section three}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section one}
\section{Section two}

\chapter*{\bibname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}

\end{document}
```

In spite of my code, I'd like to have in any case the page number in the Table of contents for Bibliography. Is there a way to change *locally* the setting for that voice? Thanx!

=======================================================================

ADDENDUM
Almost perfect. I don't understand why, but I obtain
[image]
where the page number of Bibliography is a little too on the right... In my case I've to set `{\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr30pt +1.75em\relax][l]{\thecontentspage}}}`, but only by trials and errors...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution works independently of the page number of the bibliography...

1. Remember to use

   ```
   \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   \chapter*{\bibname}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
   ```

   to have your bibliography printed and in the ToC.
2. Define the numberless-entry-format for `\chapter` in the same way you've defined it for the other sectioning commands:

   ```
   \titlecontents{chapter}[4pc]
   {\addvspace{1pc}}
   {\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[30pt][r]{\textsc{\romannumeral\thecontentslabel\quad}}}}
   {\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentspage\quad\makebox[30pt][r]{}}}
   {}
   ```

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ hoyningen:1993,
  author         = "Hoyningen-Huene, Paul",
  title          = "Recontructing Scientific Revolutions",
  publisher      = "The University of Chicago Press",
  location       = "Chicago",
  year           = "1993",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}


\contentsmargin{0pt}

\titlecontents{chapter}[4pc]
{\addvspace{1pc}}
{\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[30pt][r]{\textsc{\romannumeral\thecontentslabel\quad}}}}
{\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentspage\quad\makebox[30pt][r]{}}}
{}

\titlecontents{section}[4pc]
{}
{\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentspage\quad\makebox[30pt][r]{\textsc{\thecontentslabel.\quad}}}}
{}
{}

\titlecontents{subsection}[4pc]
{}
{\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentspage\quad\makebox[30pt][r]{\textsc{\thecontentslabel.\quad}}}}
{}
{}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section one}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section one}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section one}

\chapter{Chapter Four}
\section{Section one}

\chapter{Chapter Five}
\section{Section one}

\chapter{Chapter Six}
\section{Section one}

\chapter{Chapter Seven}
\section{Section one}

\chapter{Chapter Eight}
\section{Section one}

\chapter{Chapter Nine}
\section{Section one}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Some remarks:

1. If you set

   ```
   \contentsmargin{0pt}
   ```

   once and don't want to change it, you don't need to repeat it.
2. You are using the second mandatory argument of `\titlecontents` as it was the third...

   In other words, you should write

   ```
   \titlecontents{section}[4pc]
   {}
   {\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentspage\quad\makebox[30pt][r]{\textsc{\thecontentslabel.\quad}}}}
   {}
   {}
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   \titlecontents{section}[4pc]
   {\contentsmargin {0 pt}\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentspage\quad\makebox[30pt][r]{\textsc{\thecontentslabel.\quad}}}}
   {}
   {}
   {}
   ```

Comment: Thanx for your solution, which works very fine and for the improvements of my code. regarding 1), in my original text I've `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\chapter*{\bibname}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\markboth{\scshape bibliografia}{\scshape bibliografia}
\printbibliography[heading=testi,category=testi]
\printbibliography[heading=generalia,category=generalia]
\printbibliography[heading=antichita,category=antichita]` and so on, I don't know if there is a better code here too

Comment: @user41063 Glad it helped. About your specific setting, open a new question with a well constructed MWE. Me or someone more skilled than me will surely help you. :-)

Comment: thanx both, you and Bernard

Answer (score 3):

You can define the formatting for numberless chapters:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ hoyningen:1993,
  author = "Hoyningen-Huene, Paul",
  title = "Recontructing Scientific Revolutions",
  publisher = "The University of Chicago Press",
  location = "Chicago",
  year = "1993",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0pt}
\titlecontents{chapter}[4pc]{\addvspace{1pc}}
{\makebox[0pt][r]{\quad\makebox[30pt][r]{\textsc{\romannumeral
\thecontentslabel\quad}}}}
{\llap{\makebox[\dimexpr30pt +1.5em\relax][l]{\thecontentspage}}}
{}


\titlecontents{section}[4pc]
{\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentspage\quad\makebox[30pt][r]{\textsc{\thecontentslabel.\quad}}}}
{}
{}
{}

\titlecontents{subsection}[4pc]
{\makebox[0pt][r]{\thecontentspage\quad\makebox[30pt][r]{\textsc{\thecontentslabel.\quad}}}}
{}
{}
{}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\usepackage[style=philosophy-verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter One}
\section{Section one}
\section{Section two}

\chapter{Chapter Two}
\section{Section one}
\section{Section two}
\section{Section three}

\chapter{Chapter Three}
\section{Section one}
\section{Section two}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
\printbibliography
```

[image]
    \end{document}